# Python - Dictionary to YAML dump - YAML doesn't expand ordereddicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, ordereddictionary, ruamel.yaml

I'm dumping a fairly large dictionary into a YAML file. Instead of expanding, the file keeps an ordereddictionary as the value

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
import json

with open(file) as file:
    data = yaml.load(file, yaml.RoundTripLoader)
data = json.loads(json.dumps(data))

data.update(other_dict)

with open("file_new.yaml", "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(data, file, default_flow_style=False, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

Desired Output

```
Hello:
    Hello: 
       Hello: Hi there
       Hello2: Hi
```

Actual Output

```
Hello:
    Hello: ordereddict(["Hello": "Hi there", "Hello2": "Hi"])
```

Comment: Please supply a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code references unknown variables (`file`, `other_dict`) and unknown files. If you give the original YAML content as string in your code and write the output to `stdout`, it is far easier for others to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many places where things go wrong in your code, especially since you load with the round-trip loader using an API that ruamel.yaml is in the process of  deprecating.

The round-trip loader does all kinds of special things to preserve comments (and some other things), and then you dump the resulting data to JSON, which will not preserve the comments in any event and load the resulting JSON.

So the first thing to do is rewrite your code and run it this way:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import json

yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
with open(file) as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
# data = json.loads(json.dumps(data))
# data.update(other_dict)
yaml2 = YAML()  # the round-trip defaults to default_flow_style = False
with open('file_new.yaml', 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump(data, file)
```

and if that runs without getting the ordereddict line, uncomment the two commented lines one-by-one to determine which step adds the problem.  A third step to try is to change `typ='safe'` to `typ='rt'`.

And if the problem already occurs without doing any of these steps, you should reduce your input YAML file to the minimum that produces the problem, and then file an [issue report](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/tickets/), providing the minimal YAML that triggers the problem, the actual program, the version of ruamel.yaml and the version of Python you are using.